# any possibility to call C# function with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, com, ms-office, comvisible

I wrote an office addin and with which there is a function : openFile(String path)
and in the office addin I embed a browser object and with that I can embed a webpage on the office addin, and now I hope I can call the C# function "openFile" and pass in a path in the webpage with javascript, and let office open the designated file for me .
Is this possible ? What can I do ?

Comment: @Pato and @Rodney Foley: I think you've misunderstood the question.  We're **not** dealing with a ASP.NET client/server environment.  The C# code @MemoryLeak is talking about is running locally in a DLL.

Comment: It is our fault that MemoryLeak wasn't clear enough? I mean apparently two people not just one misunderstood. Is that any reason to down vote them?  Just up vote the one he apparently understand and answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

This is done via the `window.external` property (and [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) on the host side). See [WebBrowser Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) under the FAQ.

Happy coding.

**Edit:** However, there is likely not a way to access the value supplied to a file upload field unless you use a BHO -- this is a secondary question/issue, if it exists.